# How to run sequentially two tasks on linux

Tags: shell-script, control-flow

I'm using a keycloak server, when I run this command:

```
standalone.sh
```

This command launchs the server and I'm not able to stop it until I execute Ctrl-C command. I though about runing an instruction like this:

```
standalone.sh && jboss-cli.sh -c --commands=shutdown
```

or

```
standalone.sh ; jboss-cli.sh -c --commands=shutdown
```

Based on this question [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators) I found that `;`

> Will run one command after another has finished, irrespective of the outcome of the first.

And `&&`

> Used to build AND lists, it allows you to run one command only if another exited successfully.

But in my case the first task did not exit and still executing. Is there any solution to run another task which will stop the first?

Comment: Does the second command stop the first? When would you want to run that second command? After a certain time?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes the second will stop the first after the first will be executed

Comment: But the first one does not finish? I'm assuming it's running something in the foreground that prevent it from actually exiting and giving back control to you script. What does the first script look like?

Comment: Actually the first instruction is the script which launchs a server after that the server still in execution so I'm trying to execute the second instruction to stop it.

Comment: If I run the first in a single instance and run the second in another terminal instance. The server stops however using the two instructions in the same line did not fix the problem.

Comment: Are you just looking for `&`? Running `standalone.sh &` will run it in the background, so you will still have access to the terminal and can run `jboss-cli.sh -c --commands=shutdown` whenever you want.

Comment: This question is unclear: It is unclear whether you want to start the keycloak server with the first script and the _immediately_ shut it down with the second command, or whether the first script is supposed to start the server, do some things, and _then_ the server should be shut down. We don't know what your first script is doing or what it needs to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a single `&` at the end of the first command.

```
standalone.sh & jboss-cli.sh -c --commands=shutdown
```

That single ampersand is a command delimiter, just like `;`, but sends the prior command to run asynchronously, in the background, and lets the following command(s) start immediately.

Comment: This will also stop the first task immediately, which may not be wanted (?)

Comment: @Kusalananda - no, it should not. From `man bash`: "If a command is terminated by the control operator &,  the  shell  executes  the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is  0. Try, for instance `xclock -digital -update 1 & xclock -digital -update 1` (The second instance may overlay the first, so you may need to move the top window)

Comment: @Kusalananda - you may be confusing the ampersand delimiter with the `C-z` "suspend" keybinding.

Comment: What I mean is that if I'm reading the question correctly, the first script will start some servire, and the second command will shut it down. If you run `start-service-script & shutdown-service-command` then the service will not be running for very long.

Comment: @Kusalananda - yes, that is exactly what the OP is indicating in his *example*, which I reflected back to him/her. Your comment is probably best directed at the OP, so we can both know for sure the intent, but I suspect it was just presented as an example.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [user1404316](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153769/user1404316), `standalone.sh & jboss-cli.sh -c --commands=shutdown` is probably what you want. The only issue with that is that if the `standalone.sh` takes time to execute (which it probably does), I would insert a `sleep` to offset the execution time such as:

`standalone.sh & sleep $amount_of_time_in_seconds; jboss-cli.sh -c --commands=shutdown`